# How to dynamically change gridviewrow color based on gridviewcell value during page/grid load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having a gridview with databound values.I have 5 rows in "ReportMain" table with fields (Id,Date,Time,Name,Area,Work,Description,Priority,status) and i am showing all 5 rows in gridview (gridview name "gridview1" at run-time using linq query in c# asp.net and at run-time in those 5 rows (3 row status is "completed" and other 2 rows status is "Pending").Now i want to display the rows with the status field as "completed" in green color and the other 2 rows without any color during load. All row cell values have values and they are not null..

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var query = from row in db.ReportMains select row;
        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void chkRow_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow gdrow = (GridViewRow)checkbox.NamingContainer;

    if (checkbox.Checked)
    {
        gdrow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
        int rowindex = gdrow.RowIndex;
        int i = Convert.ToInt32( gdrow.Cells[0].Text);
        string a = gdrow.Cells[3].Text.ToString();          

        var Query = (from row in db.ReportMains where row.EmployeeName==a && row.Id==i
                     select new
                     {
                        row.EmployeeName,row.Id
                     }).Distinct();
        if (Query.Count() > 0)
        {
            var Q1 = from row in db.ReportMains where row.Id == Query.Single().Id select row;
            Q1.Single().Status = "Completed";
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }           
    }      

    else
    {
        gdrow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MintCream;
        int rowindex = gdrow.RowIndex;
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(gdrow.Cells[0].Text);
        string a = gdrow.Cells[3].Text.ToString(); 
        var Query = (from row in db.ReportMains
                     where row.EmployeeName == a && row.Id == i
                     select new
                     {
                         row.EmployeeName,
                         row.Id
                     }).Distinct();
        var Q1 = from row in db.ReportMains where row.Id == Query.Single().Id select row;
        Q1.Single().Status = null;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    ReportMain rm = (ReportMain)e.Row.DataItem;
    string st = rm.Status;
    bool isCompleted = st == "Completed";
    e.Row.BackColor = isCompleted ? Color.Green : Color.White;

}
```

Please help...

Comment: I have removed my comments and posted it as answer.

Comment: Now that you've shown your source, you haven't used my code below, especially the `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)` is missing. The first row is the header which has no `DataItem`, that's causing the `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use the rows [`DataItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx) to get the underlying `DataSource`:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row   = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        string name   = row.Field<string>("Name");
        string dept   = row.Field<string>("Dept");
        string work   = row.Field<string>("Work");
        string status = row.Field<string>("Status");
        bool isCompleted = status == "Completed"; // or status.Equals("Completed", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        e.Row.BackColor = isCompleted ? Color.Green : Color.White;
    }
}
```

I'd use the `RowDataBound` event since that is triggered for every row in the `GridView` only during data-inding(after `gridView1.DataBind()`), so not necessarily on every postback.

> The following error is shown. Unable to cast object of type
>   'ReportMain' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

What is `ReportMain`? If it's a custom class cast `e.Row.DataItem` to it. Then you can access the properties like i did with the `DataRow` above.

For example:

```
// ....
ReportMain rm = (ReportMain) e.Row.DataItem;
string name   = rm.Name;
string dept   = rm.Dept;
string work   = rm.Work;
string status = rm.Status;
bool isCompleted = status == "Completed"; // or status.Equals("Completed", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
e.Row.BackColor = isCompleted ? Color.Green : Color.White;
```

Comment: @Karthick: what is `ReportMain`? If it's a custom class cast `e.Row.DataItem` to that. Then you can access the properties like i did with the `DataRow`. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Karthick: then `e.Row.DataItem` was `null`. How and where have you assigned the `DataSource` of the `GridView`, show us that code. What is `ReportMain`, why is it `null`?

Comment: @Karthick: you haven't mentioned why the datasource is null on data-binding. However, if you don't want to use the source directly you could also read the `Cell.Text`. Presuming that the status is the 9th column: `bool isCompleted = e.Row.Cells[8].Text == "Completed";
e.Row.BackColor = isCompleted ? Color.Green : Color.White;`

Comment: @Karthick: now that you've posted your source i've noticed that you haven't used my code. You have omitted the `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)`-check which is important since the first row is the `Header` which has no `DataItem`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur patience in helping me...Now i understood my mistake and got the exact result....